# Oracle clob to String in JSP

Tags: jsp, jdbc, oracle10g

I am using JSP to access Oracle 10g. One of the table includes a field with clob data type.

When it is retrieved with getString API and be assigned to String type, it gives an error (java.sql.SQLException: Conversion to String failed)

I found that it only happens if the Statement is prepared with parameter ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE (not FORWARE ONLY)

Is there any workaround as I need to use those API of ResultSet to play around the ResultSet later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I found the way. In order to use `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` for `ResultSet`, the clob field cannot be get with `getString`. It needs to be retrieved by using `getClob`.

That's what I did:

```
clobObj         = rsJobList.getClob(6);
strTemp[4]  = clobObj.getSubString(1, (int)clobObj.length());
```

Then the string can be obtained.

Can anyone comment whether my method is ok? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to a string in the query itself. For example:

```
select TO_CHAR(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'EMP', 'SCOTT')) DETAILS from dual
```

This works fine for me.